# rsync multiple files with colons in their names

Tags: linux, rsync

`rsync` interprets colons in file names as indicators that preceding is a remote machine name. When you try to rsync a file that has a colon in it's name, rsync typically gets confused, producing errors like

```
The source and destination cannot both be remote.
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1166) [Receiver=3.0.9]
```

or

```
Unexpected remote arg: 02\:12\:43.481000"
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1232) [sender=3.0.9]
```

(notice that my use case is a bunch of files with dates in their names)

How can I use rsync to selectively send files using wild cards. Something like:

```
rsync -avz my_special_files* othermachine:/other/path/
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it from the parent directory:

```
rsync -avz parent_directory/my_special_files* othermachine:/other/path/
```

and it works (at least on ubuntu 12.04 with rsync 3.09 protocol version 30).

The reason? something to do with the logic rsync uses to recognise hosts. Forward slashes preceded by words seem not to be considered hosts. Strangely, when I used `find`, so that the names all had "./" prepended, it still didn't work.

There's a few discussions out there on this sort of issue, [for example this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rsync-scp-file-name-with-colon-punctuation-in-it/), but they don't talk about using wild cards and the like. They did, however, inspire me to try what worked in the end.